# Why can't I installed 'requests package' by pip3 on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

(I use Catalina 10.15.7)
I need 'requests package' so I'm trying to install, but I've been failing..

I wrote "% pip3 install requests" on terminal then show me like this.

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (1.26.9)
```

So I wrote add '-m' "% python3 -m pip install requests" on terminal then show me like this.

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from requests) (2021.10.8)
```

And I wrote "% pip3 --version" than, (I wrote "% pip --version" then command not found pip)

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 22.0.4 from /Users/sjpark/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

> So I try update like this "% python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip" then,

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (22.0.4)

(
"% echo $HOME" = /Users/sjpark

"% echo $PATH" = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

and I don't have '.zshrc' folder when I wrote "% ls -a"

I have both 'Python 2.7.16' and 'Python 3.8.2'

Is I have WRONG PATH ?? or WRONG VERSION ??

I'm guessing that computer doesn't know which one is real because it has two versions of Python.

Comment: It seems like requests is already installed for `python3.8`, which is the default interpreter for `python3`. So if you run `python3` or Python3's IPYthon, you should be able to import `requests`. Please note that you may be using a different interpreter normally. Also, I recommend using `python3 -m pip install $package --user`, so you install to the user directory explicitly rather than implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output; `requests` 2.27.1 *is already installed* for Python 3.8:

```
 Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (2.27.1)
```

Comment: Than I have to remove version 2.x ??

Comment: @sloth No, Python packages are installed specific for a Python interpreter version. If you install a package for Python 3.8, then it won't be available for Python 2.7. You just need to ensure you either install requests for Python 2.7, or (preferably, since Python 2.7 is end-of-life) run all scripts using Python 3.8.

Comment: @Alexander Huszagh Thank you:) Then I'm not trying remove both Python 2.7 and 3.8.. So then Why can't I install it when the requirements have already been met?

Comment: @sloth Because you're trying to install it for Python 3.8 (actually, it's already been installed), and presumably you're running your script using Python 2.7. That's why the log above shows it's already installed (for 3.8), but it seems you can't import the package.

Comment: @Alexander Huszagh Oh I see. I really thank you!! :) Then I have ALREADY but, it's running other path..! After all, it seems to be a PATH problem, and I think it is necessary to set the environment variable in '.zshrc'. Did I understand correctly?